# Python: Decorator that reduces number of parameters in a function by fixing others

Tags: python, decorator

Let's say that I have the function

```
def add(a,b,c):
return a+b+c
```

I want a decorator that fixes the value of b, say to 5, and return a function with only two parameters a and c.

```
def add5(a,c):
return a+c+5
```

The function add5 should not have any other parameter. I'm not looking to solve this with a default parameters for b.

Comment: You decorator simply has to return `add5`.

Comment: Will you be using arguments as positional arguments xor named arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

> functools.partial(func, /, *args, **keywords)
>
> Return a new partial
>   object which when called will behave like func called with the
>   positional arguments args and keyword arguments keywords.

```
from functools import partial

def add(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c
```

If you want to give a fixed value to the first positional argument, you can do

```
add5 = partial(add, 5)
print(add5(1, 2))
# 8
```

As the first positional argument (a) will be replaced by 5, you can't do:

```
print(add5(a=3, b=4))
# TypeError: add() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

If you want to control which parameter you fix, use keyword arguments:

```
add5 = partial(add, b=5)
print(add5(a=1, c=2))
# 8
```

Comment: Many thanks, partial was exactly what I needed. Super handy.

Comment: Mine was first upvote to this answer. I wonder why? This deserved kudos as it is extremely well explained.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions are the first class objects, which means that –

**Functions are objects; they can be referenced to, passed to a variable and returned from other functions as well.**

**Functions can be defined inside another function and can also be passed as argument to another function.**

Decorators are very powerful and useful tool in Python since it allows programmers to modify the behavior of function or class. Decorators allow us to wrap another function in order to extend the behavior of wrapped function, without permanently modifying it.

In Decorators, functions are taken as the argument into another function and then called inside the wrapper function.

*in your case:*

```
def my_custom_decorator(f):
    def outer_function(*args):
        res = f(*args)
        return res + 5
    return outer_function


@my_custom_decorator
def A_and_C(a, c):
    return a+c


print(A_and_C(2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
def add5(*arg):
    return sum(args)+5

print(add5(1,2))
```

This will sum all the argument that you are passing to the function and will add 5 to the sum of the args.
Output

```
8
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking to change the original function. It should be decorated in such a way that param b is fixed. I just used this example to illustrate what I need.